# Prevent user from editing phone number in account kit

Tags: facebook, account-kit

[image: Facebook account kit landing page]

I am already passing phone number to initiate facebook's account kit. Why would I re-renter the phone number here. I want the user should not edit the phone number and directly should land to the next page which is the OTP page.

Please help me.

Comment: _“Why would I re-renter the phone number here”_ - because I might simply want to use a difference number, than the one Facebook automatically suggests …?

Comment: @CBroe But it increases a action button click event. And if the user enters a different number say n2 then how will you validate the phone number n1 actually on your end after getting a callback response from account kit which authenticated a different number n2?

Comment: If we could get mobile number in the response, only then you can reverify the number that was passed from your app and understand if it was changed or not through account kit.

Comment: any one get an answer for this

Comment: Did you solve this ?@Jagmeet